# indesign paragraph spacing ignored after table

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a paragraph style that specifies 12pt spacing before the paragraph. Works fine, except when the paragraph follows a table and then the spacing is ignored.
[image]

but the paragraph options clearly show the 12 pt spacing
[image]

Why is that being ignored?

EDIT
It certainly appears to be the import. I've tried all variations with table style, including setting basic table and ensuring i don't have any other table styles defined and it always imports at 0p4 -0p4. Help

Comment: What’s the _Space after_ setting for the table? If memory serves, it’s normally -2.411mm or something like that by default.

Comment: Hmm, it's not a table. It was a table in Word, the paragraph styles came across but it doesn't seem to be a table now. It must be when i place the Word doc into indesign. Should i be doing something special for tables, other than making sure the paragraph styles are defined?

Comment: Are you sure? It certainly looks an awful lot like a table in your screenshot. Aside from making a bunch of individual little text frames and stacking them up next to each other, I don’t know how you’d create such a table-looking structure if not with an actual table…

Comment: Well that's what i thought, but if i go to the black arrow, and click none of the table options are available. I'm new to indesign, so not sure if i really have a table or not.

Comment: What happens if you double-click somewhere on the text in the table (so you can select/edit the actual text), then hit escape? If it’s a table, it will highlight the cell (entire cell gets black background); if it’s a text frame, it will select the frame (no black background).

Comment: Ok text selector first, then select table and yes it is a table.

Comment: Space after is -0p4. Why would the import set it like that, and why don't i have the 2p0 space from the paragraph.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the import – I’ve never really understood it either, but that is the default spacing after a table in InDesign. If the top spacing of the paragraph is three times the negative spacing after the table, though, there should still be more spacing than you’re seeing there. No overrides on the paragraph?

Comment: No overrides on the table. I'll try and play with the import to see if that is a potential issue. If i manually play with the space after, that works but there are 100's of tables and i don't want to manually touch each one.

Comment: Just another little thing that could affect the resulting space: Are you aware that the *Paragraph Style* of the paragraph where the table is nested also plays a role? If for example the normal text aligns to baseline grid and the paragraph style in the paragraph with the table doesn't, unexpected things happen.

Comment: You need to put a full return after the table for the space to activate - Show Hidden Characters (in type menu) and you can see what is happening

Comment: I was going to point out what @Wolff pointed out. The table, if inline, is encased in a paragraph of it's own. *that* paragraph style matters and is typically combined with any table styles (spacing). So the default table space after of -.0p4 plus a paragraph style with 0 space after means -0p4 space after... a paragraph style with +0p6 space after and the table default of -0p4 space after amounts to 0p2 space after...etc.

Comment: OK, putting the return in seems to work using the hidden character trick.. But how do i get that character in the Word doc?  I can't insert a return at the end of the table, it has to appear in front of the next line of text. Create a style just for that return?

Comment: A style can't add characters.